# Get scale of how many inputs are connected

Tags: integrated-circuit

I'm looking for specific IC, don't know what it would be called or even if something like this exists, but I'll try to describe what I need.

It should have at least 4 inputs (the more the better) and serial or parallel output. Lets assume that IC has 8 inputs and 4 bit output.
What I like this IC to do is to tell me what number of inputs are connected. For example if none is connected it would return 0 if all wires are connected I would get 4.

Now this is simplified case, because I would like to get a value even if they are connected in separate pairs (4 and 4), then it could return 3.

Value I would like to receive is scale of how much of those wires are connected. Is there anything like this out there, or should I use some combination of IC's? Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Connected to what? And what does "connected in separate pairs" mean? Perhaps you should take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve, rather than presupposing a solution. (Shopping questions are off-topic here anyway.)

Comment: two steps: realy describe your problem (as Dave said, what you state gives a hint but is not clear enough), then pay a professional to design the circuit (probably mostly protection stuff) and program the unavoidable micro-controller.

Comment: Sorry I don't know what is shopping question. I have 20 small wires (imagine a brush) and I would like to know how many of them are touching each other. It doesn't have to be precise but a rating from 0-10. I added Image as visual guide

Comment: How quickly will the wires changes state, how often do you need to know the number? Can wire #1 reach all the way to wire #20, the way you have drawn it, it doesn't look like it can, so is there a sub set?

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVQ8qw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Analog bristle connection sensor.*

This circuit feeds a 1 mA signal along a chain of 1k resistors. A wire / bristle is connected to each junction. If all bristles are disconnected the voltage read by VM1 will be N volts where N is the number of bristles. Each shorted pair will reduce the voltage by 1 V.

Note that the circuit assumes that bristles can't short to the second bristle down without touching the one in between.

Comment: Oh thank you, this would work, except that last bristle could touch first one. I could make some changes to keep them at maximum between 3 of them. But thanks this is definitely a good backup.

Comment: This would be a whole lot easier on all of us if you explain what the devices are and what you are testing for. Why do you need to know a _count_ rather than just that one or more are shorted? Can you use a micro? Is it an industrial application that you could use a PLC to solve?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use two arrays of shift registers. One array of serial-in, parallel out to generate a signal (0 or 1), and an array of parallel-in, serial out to detect connections. They would be connected to a microcontroller like an Arduino. Software would SCAN through each output pin, and then scan all the input pins to detect a connection.

Of course, since we know nothing of your application, we don't know whether this would be practical in your case.

Ref: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ShiftIn

Ref: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ShiftOut